# How to get feature names when using onehot encoder on only certain columns sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have read many posts on this that reference the `get_feature_names()` from sklearn which appears to be now deprecated and replaced by `get_feature_names_out` neither of which I can get to work. It also appears that there is no way to use the get_feature_names (or the get_feature_names_out)  with the ColumnTransformer class. So I am trying to fit and transform my numeric columns with a SimpleImputer and then StandardScaler class then SimpleImpute ('most_frequent') and OneHotEncode the categorical variables. I run them all individually since I can't put them in a pipeline then I try to get_feature_names and this results:

```
ValueError: input_features should have length equal to number of features (5), got 11
```

I have also tried getting feature names for just the categorical features as well as just the numeric and each one give the following errors respectively:

```
ValueError: input_features should have length equal to number of features (5), got 121942
```

and

```
ValueError: input_features should have length equal to number of features (5), got 121942
```

I am completely lost and also open to an easier way to get the feature names so that I can make sure the prod data that I run this model on after training/testing has the exact same features as the ones the model is trained to expect (which is the root issue here).

If I'm "barking up the wrong tree" by trying to get the feature names for the reasoning outlined in the root issue I'm also more than willing to be corrected. Here is my code:

```
#ONE HOT
import sklearn
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
# !pip install -U scikit-learn
print('The scikit-learn version is {}.'.format(sklearn.__version__))

numeric_columns = X.select_dtypes(include=['int64','float64']).columns
cat_columns = X.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns


si_num = SimpleImputer(strategy='median')
si_cat = SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')

ss = StandardScaler()
ohe = OneHotEncoder()

si_num.fit_transform(X[numeric_columns])
si_cat.fit_transform(X[cat_columns])
ss.fit_transform(X[numeric_columns])
ohe.fit_transform(X[cat_columns])

ohe.get_feature_names(X[numeric_columns])
```

Thanks!

Comment: "It also appears that there is no way to use the get_feature_names (or the get_feature_names_out) with the ColumnTransformer class."  Huh?  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html#sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.get_feature_names_out

Comment: @BenReiniger this github issue might help clarify: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/21452

Comment: That issue is about specifying columns by name to a column transformer that isn't first in a pipeline.

Comment: It would help to explain how your different errors relate to the code snippet you supplied. Note to that in your code snippet you don't ever assign the transformed output to anything.

Comment: And do I understand correctly that the ideal solution is just a single composite estimator that performs the 4 stated transformations and admits a method to get feature names?

Comment: @BenReiniger Yes the goal is to put all of those estimators into one single pipeline and run the dataframe through them then get all the resulting feature names. You're right I didn't assign the result to anything. What I should have done is assigned `X = ohe.get_feature_names(X[numeric_columns])`. The goal is then split, train,  test then run the model on "real world" data. When I one hot encode my real world data I get over 1000 features whereas the train data has 680. I need to make the real world features match the train features and that's why I want the feature names. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work as a single composite estimator that does all your transformations and provides `get_feature_names_out`:

```py
num_pipe = Pipeline([
    ("imp", si_num),
    ("scale", ss),
])
cat_pipe = Pipeline([
    ("imp", si_cat),
    ("ohe", ohe),
])
preproc = ColumnTransformer([
    ("num", num_pipe, numeric_columns),
    ("cat", cat_pipe, cat_columns),
])
```

Ideally, you should save the fitted composite and use that to transform production data, rather than using the feature names to reconcile different categories.

You should also fit this composite only on the training set, transforming the test set separately.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked great! The one followup question I have is when you say `save the fitted composite and use that to transform the production data`... With onehotencoding specifically if train data has categorical values in one column of 'x','y','z' OneHotEncoder will create separate features of each. If prod data has values 'c','d' in the equivalent column then OneHotEncoder will create those as features too but the model isn't fit for them. I'm still confused on that. The options seem to be use label encoding instead or add `handle_unknown = 'ignore'. any thoughts?

Comment: With the default `handle_unknown='error'`, it will just break.  Changing that to `'ignore'` will transform the new categories into a row of all zeros (in the dummies for that feature), which is probably the best you can hope for; there's no way to tell your model what to do with categories it can't see in the training data.  You **should not** `fit` the composite on prod data: the encoding for one, but also the scalers should be using the statistics learned from the training set.

Comment: Hi Ben, so to make sure I understand you. I am only fitting the model on my train data to train the model then I import the trained model to the file with the prod data and preprocess the prod data to get it into the exact same state as the data used to train the model (same shape/number of columns same values in each feature column, same encoding scaling etc). The model needs everything to be preprocessed exactly the same because it can't know about unknown feature values that it wasn't trained on. So with this in mind you're saying handle_unknown = 'ignore' is the best option in this case?

Comment: @JustinBenfit Yes to everything up to the last sentence For the last sentence, I think there _could_ be more clever approaches depending on details, but that "ignore" or "error" are the right generic choices; that starts to become off-topic here.